# How to use function containing URL in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My Swift code is below. My question is how to use the function `deleteRecording` in selected row at tableView.

```
//select which row I want to delete....

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        print("Deleted")
        showAlert(message: "Delete?")
        self.recordings.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}

// plist data and delete the recording data

func deleteRecording(_ url: URL) {
    print("removing file at \(url.absoluteString)")
    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    do {
        try fileManager.removeItem(at: url)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        print("error deleting recording")
    }
    //Reappear the rows of tableView
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.listRecordings()
        self.tableView?.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to get the URL from `self.recordings` before you call `remove(at:)`. At least I'm assuming that array contains the URL in some fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly **tableView.deleteRows** will automatically update your table view, you don't need to reload the table. But before that, you have to delete the file and update your list. Just your simple **commit editingStyle** do that work.

See the sample code below and adjust your code:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
 //get your path from URL
   let path = getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("Recording\(indexPath.row + 1).m4a")
   if editingStyle == .delete {
    do{
       // delete file and update your list 
        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: path)
         self.listRecordings()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)

    } catch{
        displayAlert(title: "OOPS", message: "Delete failed")
    }
  }
}
```